# How do i create a overlay tutorial message in android.?

Tags: android

> Now a days most new application are coming with help message for the first time

Comment: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code snippet

```
    public void helpOverlay(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.coach_mark);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.coach_mark_master_view);
    masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

or [here is a github project](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)